# knitr: include test that on purpose fails in output PDF

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to add tests (not to test Rmd file, but include test in the document) to Rmd file which fail, but I can't generate pdf using knitr, because it stops on failed test. How to achieve this? Code:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r, error=TRUE}
    library(testthat)
    expect_equal(1, 2)
```

```{r, error=TRUE}
    library(testthat)
    expect_equal(1, 1)
```
````

Env:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] backports_1.0.5 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.1     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.9    
 [8] stringi_1.1.2   rmarkdown_1.3   knitr_1.15.1    stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `test_that`. The following code works perfectly:

````
```{r, error=TRUE}
    library(testthat)
    test_that(1, expect_equal(1, 2))
```

```{r, error=TRUE}
    test_that(2, expect_equal(1, 1))
```
````

Note that the first argument in `test_that` is a name for the test.

Comment: It seems that previous format works with testthat_0.11.0 and with up to date lib your approach is needed. Thx